# Adding localStorage To Javascript Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I needed a countdown timer so I added this Javascript coding to my website page. The only problem is that the timer resets every single time a person clicks on the reload button in their browser. Somebody told me that I need to add **localStorage** to stop this from happening. What lines of coding do I need to add to fix this problem?

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  function timer() {
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (diff <= 0) {
      // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
      // example 05:00 not 04:59
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
  };
  // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function() {
  var thirtyMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(thirtyMinutes, display);
};
```

Comment: You said in a comment under your previous question that you're not a coder. Stack Overflow isn't intended as a code-writing service for non-coders, it's intended to help *programmers* with problems on code that they're working on. If you want to learn to be a coder then great, welcome. But as the [Stack Overflow Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) says, don't ask questions "you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: I'd suggest you do a Google search on how to use `localStorage` from Javascript, runs some sample code you find in that search and then come back  here if you have a more specific question about how to implement your specific solution.  As the previous comment said, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: The person who suggested I add localStorage provided me with a link but I couldn't figure it out on my own. I thought this would be as simple as adding two lines of coding to the script. Judging by your answers, I'm guessing it's a little more complicated than that.